# WPF/C# - Play animation first on control then set data from binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a custom control which when is pressed/dragged it plays an animation.
It is binded to ViewModel data. The problem is that the animation is played after the data is sent through binding. I want to play the animation first, then apply the changes through the binding.

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: SO is not a picnic: Please provide a [mcve] and tell us what you tried.

Comment: I've posted my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was:
1.  to create a DependencyProperty of ICommand type which I bind to the specific command where I use my custom control. 
2. then in my custom control code I register to Storyboard.Completed event where I call my DependencyCommand Execute() method.

ex:

```
class CustomControl : Control
{
    public ICommand CustomControlCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue( CustomControlCommandProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( CustomControlCommandProperty, value ); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomControlCommandProperty=
        DependencyProperty.Register( nameof( CustomControlCommand), typeof( ICommand ), typeof( CustomControl),
            new PropertyMetadata( null ) );


    // this is called in mouse down event handler
    private void PlayAnimation()
    {
        var myStoryboard = new Storyboard();
        myStoryboard.Completed += StoryboardCompleted;
        //.... animation
    }

    private void StoryboardCompleted( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        CustomControlCommand?.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

and binding the command in xaml:

```
<customcontrol:CustomControl CustomControlCommand="{Binding MyControlFromVM}"/>
```